# The Windows currency symbol

Tags: c#, .net, windows-7, localization

I'd like to get the currency symbol used by Windows; this symbol can be viewed and modified using the *Region and Language* option from the control panel.

`RegionInfo.CurrentRegion` represents the regional information of the language used in the current thread; `RegionInfo.CurrentRegion.CurrencySymbol` therefore will not necessarily match the currency symbol as selected by the user of the operating system.

If I modify just the currency symbol in *Region and Language* > *Advanced settings...* > *Currency*, I'd like to be able to access that symbol from a C# program. How can this be done?

Thank you for reading my post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `RegionInfo` does not reflect user-changed settings. I think something like

```
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol
```

will work.

**ADDITION** (after answer was accepted):

I tested a bit, and it seems that in some cases `RegionInfo` **does** reflect user-settings. Even though [the spec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Globalization.RegionInfo.aspx) says: *In contrast to CultureInfo, RegionInfo does not represent preferences of the user and does not depend on the user's language or culture.*

On my Windows 7 pc, I get this result: `RegionInfo` does reflect the user-settings, even if I construct a `new` instance of `RegionInfo` (rather than using the `CurrentRegion` getter). So now we're confused.

Comment: Thank you for the update. It seems that you have similar results as @André Christoffer Andersen. I tested both answers using two different projects (the one I actually work in and one I created just to test the results); in both cases your answer gives me exactly what I need even after multiple changes to the `Region and Language` settings. `RegionInfo` consistently gives me the correct currency symbol associated with the culture of the running thread regardless of the OS settings.

Comment: @Pooven Interesting. What version of the .NET Framework and Visual Studio do you use? Maybe they changed something.

Comment: That's a good point. I'm using .NET 3.5 SP1 with Visual Studio 2008 V9 SP.

Comment: I used VS2010 and .NET 4 SP1. I wonder if that's the reason. Maybe under some conditions the runtime does not have permissions to access the user preferences? I guess you weren't changing the settings while your application was already running?

Comment: It does make sense for `RegionInfo` to provide user elected regional settings. It does seem more reasonable for the `CurrentCulture` to provide the user's customized regional settings. If I change the currency symbol while my application is running, `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol` does not return the change; but this isn't necessarily undesired. Thank you once again for taking the time to test this :)

Answer (score 2):

It can be found inside of [RegionInfo.CurrencySymbol](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.regioninfo.currencysymbol%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: That does not exist w/o getting an instance first.

Comment: @HenkHolterman - I linked MSDN for such details.  This should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure your original assumptions are right? When I change/edit the currency symbol under "Region and Language > Additional settings > Currency > Currency symbol"

The following changes according:

```
RegionInfo.CurrentRegion.CurrencySymbol
```

Comment: That's interesting; my *original assumption*, while based on the documentation, was also based on observation. I did modify the Windows currency symbol manually and `RegionInfo.CurrencySymbol` did not update accordingly. I don't understand how we could be experiencing different behaviour? Thank you for taking the time to try this out, I appreciate your response :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's some gotchas I learned today - my code verifying my findings is below. I set my system to Spanish - Dominican Republic, and changed the currency symbol from "RD$" to "$". I then set my culture/UI culture to es-DO instead of en-US.

- Using `number.ToString("C2")` does not follow user-customized settings. So, if you set `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`/`CurrentUICulture` to es-DO and do `1.00M.ToString("C2")`, it will return RD$1.00.
- To have it actually use the user-customized settings, you have to have a `var info = new CultureInfo("es-DO")` variable and then use `string.Format(info, "{0:C2}", 1.00M)` to get the expected $1.00, as per the change above.
- You cannot use `string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "{0:C2}", 1.00M)` as it will not return user customizations - in this case, it would return RD$1.00.

I think this is silly, but if someone out there knows the real reason behind for this behavior, please share as I am curious.

Here's the code for repro:

```
var esdo = new CultureInfo("en-US");
{en-US}
esdo = new CultureInfo("es-DO");
{es-DO}
var resdo = new RegionInfo("es-DO");
{es-DO}
        CurrencyEnglishName: "Dominican Peso"
        CurrencyNativeName: "Peso"
        CurrencySymbol: "$"
        DisplayName: "Dominican Republic"
        EnglishName: "Dominican Republic"
        GeoId: 65
        IsMetric: true
        ISOCurrencySymbol: "DOP"
        Name: "es-DO"
        NativeName: "República Dominicana"
        ThreeLetterISORegionName: "DOM"
        ThreeLetterWindowsRegionName: "DOM"
        TwoLetterISORegionName: "DO"
esdo.NumberFormat
{System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo}
        CurrencyDecimalDigits: 2
        CurrencyDecimalSeparator: "."
        CurrencyGroupSeparator: ","
        CurrencyGroupSizes: {int[1]}
        CurrencyNegativePattern: 1
        CurrencyPositivePattern: 0
        CurrencySymbol: "$"
        DigitSubstitution: None
        IsReadOnly: false
        NaNSymbol: "NeuN"
        NativeDigits: {string[10]}
        NegativeInfinitySymbol: "-Infinito"
        NegativeSign: "-"
        NumberDecimalDigits: 2
        NumberDecimalSeparator: "."
        NumberGroupSeparator: ","
        NumberGroupSizes: {int[1]}
        NumberNegativePattern: 1
        PercentDecimalDigits: 2
        PercentDecimalSeparator: "."
        PercentGroupSeparator: ","
        PercentGroupSizes: {int[1]}
        PercentNegativePattern: 1
        PercentPositivePattern: 1
        PercentSymbol: "%"
        PerMilleSymbol: "‰"
        PositiveInfinitySymbol: "Infinito"
        PositiveSign: "+"
var dsa = 1.00M;
string.Format(esdo,"{0:C2}",dsa)
"$1.00"
dsa.ToString("C2")
"RD$1.00"
string.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,"{0:C2}",dsa)
"RD$1.00"
string.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture,"{0:C2}",dsa)
"RD$1.00"
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture
{es-DO}
string.Format(esdo,"{0:C2}",dsa)
"$1.00"
```

Answer (score -1):

```
//    Do something like that maybe
public static string getSeparator()
        {
            string output = string.Empty;
            try
            {
                RegistryKey reg = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Control Panel").OpenSubKey("International");
                output = reg.GetValue(EnumClass.String.sList.ToString(), output).ToString();

                reg.Dispose();
            }`enter code here`
            catch (Exception ie)
            {
                // catch error
            }
            return output;
        }
```